# How to use ssh-agent as a system service on mac

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I'd like to run ssh-agent as a system service, so I have one global ssh-agent running that is accessible from all shells and GUI programs. On Linux I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#Start_ssh-agent_with_systemd_user) to run `ssh-agent` as a systemd user service, and it works well. `ssh-agent` starts automatically on boot, and everything can access the agent via the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable.

On mac, I'm having trouble doing the same thing. The `ssh-agent` service is running and exporting a `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable. That variable points to a world-readable socket. However, when I try to use `ssh-add`, I get "no such file or directory". How can I get this to work?

```
$ launchctl list | grep com.openssh.ssh-agent
90829   -9      com.openssh.ssh-agent
$ pgrep ssh-agent
90829
$ launchctl print gui/501/com.openssh.ssh-agent | grep SSH_AUTH
                SSH_AUTH_SOCK => /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.PktEMOxKOJ/Listeners
                        secure key = SSH_AUTH_SOCK
$ file $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.PktEMOxKOJ/Listeners: socket
$ stat -f '%Sp' $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
srw-rw-rw-
$ ssh-add -l
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```

I'm setting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in `.bash_profile` like so:

```
# linux ssh-agent
[ -z "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ] && export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket"

# mac ssh-agent (dealing with weirdly inconsistent socket path)
[ -d /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.* ] && export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.*/Listeners
```

The mac implementation feels really hacky, but I wasn't sure how to deal with it creating a different path every time it starts.

Note: I'm aware you can start `ssh-agent` in the shell [like this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#ssh-agent). I've found it cleaner on linux to have it managed as a system service, and was wondering if that approach was possible on Mac.

Comment: You say the launch agent is exporting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, but that'll only get inherited by its child processes, not anything else in your user session. It looks like you're using a nonstandard socket name, and somehow `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is getting set in your shell; can you clarify exactly how this is being handled?

Comment: Sorry! I've edited the post. I'm setting in `.bash_profile`. As far as a "nonstandard socket name", I'm just using what the built-in `com.openssh.ssh-agent` service creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic problem is that the shell doesn't expand wildcards when assigning to variables, so `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` isn't getting set to the actual path to the socket, it's getting set to an unexpanded wildcard that doesn't point to any actual item.

When you test it with `stat -f '%Sp' $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, the variable reference isn't double-quoted, so it'll expand the wildcard expression at that point. But that expansion is a shell function; ssh isn't going to do it when it looks for the socket, so that's why you get an error. Try `stat -f '%Sp' "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"` to see this effect in the shell.

One possible fix is to assign to an array (where you *can* expand the wildcard immediately) instead of a plain variable:

```
# mac ssh-agent (dealing with weirdly inconsistent socket path)
possible_sockets=(/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.*/Listeners)
if [[ ${#possible_sockets[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Found multiple possible ssh-agent sockets; you should probably investigate this." >&2
fi
for possible_socket in "${possible_sockets[@]}"; do
    if [[ -e "$possible_socket" ]]; then
        export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$possible_socket"
        break
    fi
done
```

I added a check for multiple matches, because this seems like a fragile way to do things. I haven't experimented with this, but I'd be tempted to use `ssh-agent -a /some/predictable/path` to put the socket in a deterministic place.

Comment: Ah, good catch, thank you! I agree this seems fragile. I was trying to use the service included with macOS since I'm not that familiar with `launchd`, but maybe I need to write my own that uses a predictable path.